# How can I add a filter to a particular post format?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, hooks, post-formats

I have several post formats and I want to use `add_filter` selectively, applying the filter to some of the post formats but not all. When I do this in my `functions.php` file it affect all the post formats. It also affects all my custom post types which I want to avoid.

```
function test_filter($content) {
    $content = "test" . $content;
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','test_filter');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `get_post_format()`:

```
function test_filter($content) {

    $format = get_post_format();

    if ( ! $format )
        return $content;

    if ( 'audio' === $format )
        // do something with audio

    if ( 'aside' === $format )
        // do something with aside

    return "$content <hr>post format: $format";
}
```

Since `the_content()` requires a global `$post` object to work, `get_post_format()` will always work. It will return `FALSE` if the current post type does not support post formats and a post format slug otherwise.

Comment: I will try that but I'm a bit confused about how I determine which post formats the filter operates. I also don't understand why you have `<hr>post format:` in there

Comment: The extra HTML is just there to show some useful output. I made an update with better examples.